# Get Attribute of products of the products in cart at onestepcheckout

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, products

I was trying to define some exceptions, and one of them is about the volume of the product.
I've got width-length-height attributes in the products.
And i was trying to get the total of these 3 attributes of all the products at my cart.

So i was trying things like this:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $totalV= 0;

        foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {

        $prod_W = $item->getAttributeText('dp_width');
        $prod_H = $item->getAttributeText('dp_height');
        $prod_L = $item->getAttributeText('dp_length');
        $totalV += $prod_H + $prod_L +$prod_W;
        }

        ?>


        <input type = "hidden" class = "onestepcheckout-vol-prod" value = "<?php echo $totalV;?>
               " >
        </input>
```

I tries to using `$item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('X');` but it gives me an error.

How could i get these values ?

Comment: try the $item->getData('dp_width');

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Load product in foreach is a bad idea, though working.

Better way:

in `config.xml`

```
<global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <dp_width/>
                    <dp_height/>
                    <dp_length/>
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
</global>
```

And...

```
$item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('dp_width');
```

Comment: And then  i could get the attribute as `$item->getAttributeText('dp_width');`

Comment: Yes, exactly, this is the correct variant!

Comment: This is actual process +1 vote

Comment: and  for getting try `$item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('dp_width');`

Comment: Before making it, and cleaning cache, i make a try and gives me this error:
`Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object in /home/XXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php`

Comment: @Neklo.com could get a see on it?
I was trying your code, but can't get the values .
I had changed the `config.xml` of `app/etc` , is that correct?
Tryed to use `$item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('Attributes');`
But don't get any attribute, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Great! Here is an extended version of this answer: http://bit.ly/2sPph6d

Comment: perfect answer +1 vote

Answer (score 4):

you can try this:

```
$item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('dp_width')->getFrontend()->getValue($item->getProduct());

$item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('dp_length')->getFrontend()->getValue($item->getProduct());

$item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('dp_height')->getFrontend()->getValue($item->getProduct());
```

**I have Using product Resource model**

Comment: Dont run, i think it´s because this values are not printed on frontend, so it returns 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
$item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('X')
```

`$item` donot have all the attributes information in quote, so the above code will not work.

instead you can try the below code

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

$product->getAttributeText('X')
```

Comment: As you say, i try like you, But at the end, it gives me the same error as i say at final: `Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object `

Answer (score 0):

Load Product in foreach

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
$product->getAttributeText('dp_height');
```

you can able to get Product attributes like this

Comment: The same error as i say to the other mate down `Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object`

Comment: 'Show in Product Listing' needed to be set to yes in the attribute editor in admin

Comment: cannot do this .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```